# .py web scraping used in .html file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have never really worked that much with python but i'm basicly trying to get a small line of text from a website by web scraping like this:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GME/"
r = requests.get(url)
text = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
text = text.find_all('div', {'class' : 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].text

print(text)
```

and then somehow include the result of the "print(text)" line in a separate but local html file. So the problem here is that i'm not sure how i would go about making my .phy program interact with an .html file or if it's even possible.

to put simply, i have the infromation from the URl and i now want to to appear on an html website.

I'm not even sure if this is possible, would appreciate some input on this idea.

Comment: it's very much possible, but you haven't described your problem clearly enough. do you just want to print the contents of text to a file? [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) is a simple guide to writing to files. if you want something more complex then please update your questions with more detail